# Regency gas Fireplace main burner is auto igniting and won't shut off until i turn off gas valve

Tags: hvac

I have regency C34 gas fireplace probably made around 2000. Unit has worked well but recently started itself and would not shut off until I shut the gas off. This has happen every time since when I relight the pilot light...it takes about 30 seconds and the main burner will ignite and not shut off until gas is turned off.
Each time after I turn off the gas value in about 5 seconds I can hear something open/close not sure what.
This unit has an thermostat remote control  and a receiver box which runs on batteries that has an off, remote or on switch. I have removed the batteries from the remote, from the receiver even at different times and after I light the pilot in about 30 seconds the main burner ignites as mentioned above. I have moved the switch on the receiver box to off and the unit will not shut off. Please let me know what the problem could be.

Mark

Comment: Gas? Probably worth getting a professional in.. even if it's seemingly not related to the gas.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though there is a short in the wiring somewhere.  Most fireplace remotes will still function manually with the batteries removed.  The C34 utilized a SIT millevolt gas valve.  The remote controls' 2 wires will be attached to the valves "TH" terminal & the THTP" terminal (top & bottom terminals). If you remove 1 of the wires & the issue ceases, its a remote problem - & the fireplace is fine.  At 17yrs old, its probably the remote.  The reason that the burner comes on 30 seconds after lighting is because that about how long it takes for the thermopile to generate enough power to energize the valve.  The click you hear shortly after shutting off the gas is the control valve closing from the pilot being shut off - a safety device.